# Sharepoint 2010 grouped xsltlistview with custom XSL does not show items when initial settings for group is 'fold'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

Following problem :

I have a xsltListView (auto created on a publishing site). I have editted the default view and copied the stylesheet to a new .xsl file and placed it into the style lybrary.

On the page where my xsltlistview is, I have editted the listview, and pointed it to the custom .xsl file.

All loads ok.. The list is grouped, however when I want to ungroup a specific group, it says loding, and then displays not a single document. When I use the setting that it should unfold by default, the documents are diplayed

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.. You need to enable the asynchronous update..

After enabling the listitems are shown again...